# SharePoint 2013 - Detecting child role types within parent role types

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within the LoginView that I can construct on a master template, is is possible to detect a child role type within a parent role type?  If so, what is a best practice on writing something like that within a SharePoint 2013 Master page (.html)

...or is it not possible to have child roles....?

This is what I currently have in the form of a snippet...

```
<!--CS: Start Create Snippets From Custom ASP.NET Markup Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<asp:LoginView id="LoginView2" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:                <RoleGroups>-->
<!--SPM:                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Student">-->
<!--SPM:                        <ContentTemplate>-->
                                 <p>I am a student</p>
<!--SPM:                        </ContentTemplate>-->
<!--SPM:                    </asp:RoleGroup>-->
<!--SPM:                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="teacher">-->
<!--SPM:                        <ContentTemplate>-->
                                <p>I am a teacher</p>
<!--SPM:                        </ContentTemplate>-->
<!--SPM:                    </asp:RoleGroup>-->
<!--SPM:                </RoleGroups>-->
<!--SPM:            </asp:LoginView>-->
<!--CE: End Create Snippets From Custom ASP.NET Markup Snippet-->
```

...and I would like to define child roles for a student, and child roles for a teacher if that is all possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Through SharePoint there is no Permission Hierarchy. You do have a few ways to achieve it though:

1. You can implement a [SPClaimsProvider](http://www.titus.com/blog/2012/03/building-a-custom-claim-provider-to-manage-security-clearances/)
   The link implements a hierarchy for Confidential, Secret and Top Secret Roles and permissions. I don't know how the Claims Provider behaves with the login view...
2. Another alternative would be to implement the Hierarchy in a custom Role Provider.
3. And lastly, you can implement the Inheritance through AD Security Groups, putting one group inside the other, then adding that group into a SharePoint group for the desired functionality at the lowest level that has the access.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I already played with security trimmed controls. LoginView actually handles role groups, while the former does not...

Comment: AH, alright =] I actually didn't know that one. I don't think I understood your question then. Do you mean having Role A that is a child of B implies that you also have Role B?

Comment: I have edited the response =], not sure if it notifies... I am new here...